# Configuring keep-alive timeout in Elasticsearch server

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, keep-alive, tcp-keepalive

I was wondering if Elasticsearch provides a way of configuring a `keep-alive` timeout.

I can see that [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/modules-network.html) describes a `network.tcp.keep_alive` TCP setting that can be used to enable TCP Keep Alive. I'm searching for a way in Elasticsearch to configure the actual timeout value.

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.6.8.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you would have to configure this on the client.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/configuration.html#config-keep-alive-free-socket-timeout